# C# parse string using regex - number adjacent to letter

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having trouble writing a correct REGEX and parsing the string in C#.
The string I get an input is:

{EnemyMove X:7 Y:8}

I need to digits the follow X and the digits that follow Y, the range is 0-10.
Tried the code below, but the regex is incorrect and I get an incorrect result.

I need to run it twice, once to get the digits adjacent to X and second time for the digits after Y.

```
string str = "{EnemyMove X:9 Y:10}";
var regex_sp_chrs = new Regex("/X:.*?(\d+)/");
regex_sp_chrs.Matches(str );
```

Expected output - 
9
10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your string isn't a string for a start. What are you actual requirements here? How was the string generated in the first place? Do you need to worry about stuff like spaces between the `X` and the `:` or the `:` and the number. Start with a strict set of rules and your regex will write itself

Comment: `{EnemyMove X:9 Y:10}` isn't a string. Your sample code won't even compile.

Comment: @ErikE, sorry about that, must have missed it when I was writing it here, fixed now.

Comment: My next comment is that regex is not a great way to parse this. Why not just split on ` ` (space), take the resulting tokens and split them on `:`, then for each one, if the `[0]` is X or Y, use the `[1]` appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restrict the numbers to 0-10 range, replace `\d+` with `10|\d`:

```
X:(?<X>10|\d)\s+Y:(?<Y>10|\d)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=X%3a(%3f%3cX%3e10%7c%5cd)%5cs%2bY%3a(%3f%3cY%3e10%7c%5cd)&i=%7bEnemyMove+X%3a7+Y%3a8%7d)

So, you need to remove the delimiters (leading/trailing `/`) and add the `Y` part.

Group `X` will contain the digits after `X` and Group `Y` will contain the digits after `Y`.

[image]

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/vEWtRe):

```
var str = "{EnemyMove X:9 Y:10}";
var regex_sp_chrs = new Regex(@"X:(?<X>10|\d)\s+Y:(?<Y>10|\d)");
var ms = regex_sp_chrs.Matches(str);
foreach (Match m in ms)
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", 
                   m.Groups["X"].Value,
                   m.Groups["Y"].Value));
```

It will output `9 - 10`, `9` is the `m.Groups["X"].Value` and `10` is the `m.Groups["Y"].Value`.

If you know `{EnemyMove` is static (always present as a literal before `X`), add it to the regex to make it safer (i.e. `@"{EnemyMove\s+X:(?<X>\d+)\s+Y:(?<Y>\d+)"`).

Comment: Looks like that's it now. If you have any doubts, please feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: I tested the demo and I get the string 'X:7', I've managed to get to this result, but I need just the digit.

Comment: Did you use `m.Groups["X"].Value` and `m.Groups["Y"].Value`?

Comment: Please update the question with the  current code so that I could have a look. State what the expected output is.

Comment: Again, did you use `match.Groups["X"].Value` (=9) and `match.Groups["Y"].Value` (=10)?